# Регулярное выражение для nickname (Вид: "Имя(с большой буквы)_Фамилия(с большой буквы)")

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Требуется регулярное выражение которое будет допускать nickname только такого типа:

Имя(с большой буквы)_Фамилия(с большой буквы)

```
^(([a-zA-Z]{4,12})([_]{1})([a-zA-Z]{4,12}))$
```

Использую вот такое, но фамилию можно записать с маленькой

Comment: А имя разве нельзя?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ну вот, очень простая регулярка:

```
^([A-Z][a-z]{3,11})_([A-Z][a-z]{3,11})$
```

2 селектора, 1й - имя, 2й - фамилия. И имя, и фамилия обязательно начинаются с большой буквы, остальные буквы в нижнем регистре, так же знак подчеркивания обязателен и пробелы недопустимы.

Если есть желание допустить полный upper-case, можно привести это к следующему виду:

```
^([A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,11})_([A-Z][a-zA-Z]{3,11})$
```

Здесь регулярку можно опробовать на лету: https://regex101.com/